# Pythonic way for assignment a value from dictionary with possible KeyError

Tags: python, jira-rest-api

I am extracting data from jira api and there are multiple fields which either do or do not exist. So my code has a lot of the following blocks:

```
try:
    sample_field_value = i['fields']['customfield_10001']['content'][0]['content'][0]['text']
except TypeError:
    sample_field_value = None
```

I would like to have something like the following function in place instead, however, not unsurprisingly, this won't work:

```
def try_except_keyerror(x)
  try:
    return x
  except KeyError:
    return None
```

Could you tell me how to improve on the function above, so that I can somehow have a one-liner for sample_field_value assignment?

Comment: just use get method. by default it returns `None` if key doesn't exist.

Comment: one-liner != pythonic, your original approach above is fine. Although, you want to `except KeyError`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga right, of course

Answer (score 0):

You could have a method that would extract the data, and handles both

- `KeyError` when key is string, and so structure is a `dict`
- `IndexError` when key is int, and so structure is a `list` (handle empty list)

```
def jira_get(content):
    try:
        return content['fields']['customfield_10001']['content'][0]['content'][0]['text']
    except (KeyError, IndexError):
        return None

print(jira_get({}))  # None
print(jira_get({"fields": {}}))  # None
print(jira_get({"fields": {'customfield_10001': {}}}))  # None
print(jira_get({"fields": {'customfield_10001': {'content': []}}}))  # None
print(jira_get({"fields": {'customfield_10001': {'content': [{}]}}}))  # None
print(jira_get({"fields": {'customfield_10001': {'content': [{'content': []}]}}}))  # None
print(jira_get({"fields": {'customfield_10001': {'content': [{'content': [{}]}]}}}))  # None
print(jira_get({"fields": {'customfield_10001': {'content': [{'content': [{'text': 'foobar'}]}]}}}))  # foobar
```